# Kivy button text alignment issue

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to develop an email application in Kivy, basically just as an exercise to learn the in's and out's of the framework... I am trying to create the initial window and have reached a bit of a stumbling block! The idea is that it will simply display a list of emails in the inbox, much like any basic email app on a mobile device.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to get the text of each list item (which is a just a button) to align properly. Using "halign='left'" in my button will make the text align left, but only relative to each button; it's still centered within each button.

My actual app is a bit large to post, so this is a quick and dirty example I made from a stock Kivy example. (I realize this code isn't perfect... like I said quick and dirty for examples sake... it does work though!) **So as you can see, the two rows of text on each button align with each other, but they don't all align overall. Can anyone suggest what I would do to make all the text align at, say, 10px from the left of each button?** I did find one relative sounding item on StackOverflow, but it didn't really answer the question for example, it seemed to deal more with using images on buttons. I am new to Kivy, but I've read through the tutorials and documentation, as well as searched Google extensively - so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.8')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

import random


class ScrollViewApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # create a default grid layout with custom width/height
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint=(None, None),
                            width=Window.width)

        # when we add children to the grid layout, its size doesn't change at
        # all. we need to ensure that the height will be the minimum required to
        # contain all the childs. (otherwise, we'll child outside the bounding
        # box of the childs)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        # add button into that grid
        for i in range(30):
            btn = Button(text=str(i * random.random()) + '\n' + str(i * random.random()),
                         size=(300, 40),
                         size_hint=(None, None),
                         halign='left')
            layout.add_widget(btn)

        # create a scroll view, with a size < size of the grid
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None))
        root.size = (Window.width, Window.height)
        root.center = Window.center
        root.add_widget(layout)

        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The documentation of [Button](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#module-kivy.uix.button) starts with "A Button is a Label". Even for [Widgets](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.html) that don't mention their lineage explicitly, you should take a note of the second line in the [API doc](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button) of the Widget in question. In this case "Bases: kivy.uix.label.Label".

This establishes that the button inherits from a Label. (I am explicitly mentioning this because this part of looking at the base Class's inherited properties sometimes is not intuitive for everyone).

If you look at the Docs for label,  specifically the [`halign`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=text%20alignment#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign) property, it asks you to utilize [`text_size`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=text%20alignment#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size) to achieve proper text alignment. What this means is the text is aligned inside a bounding box that is set by the [`text_size`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=text%20alignment#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size) property. This property can be set to be:

a) The size of the Widget. `text_size: self.size`

b) Less than the size of the size of the widget (what you are looking for) `text_size: self.width - dp(10), self.height - dp(10)`

c) Unconstrained on one of the sides `text_size: self.width, None`

d) or both `text_size: None, None`

e) or constrained to a different Widget `text_size: other_button.size`

The reason for using `text_size` is to give more control to the user.
You should also look at the [textalign example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/textalign.py)

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `text_size` property, something like:

```
btn.text_size = (290, 40)
```

Comment: Also, having a look at the text_align example would help.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by qua-non ,**a Button is a Label** therefore you can look at the
Label proprieties in how to achieve that. 
Because I didn’t see much on this, I want to add a small piece of code that can help other programmers.
I’ll show how you can make button with label and adjust the text inside.

```
#disable multi-touch emulation
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image   
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
  BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: "10dp"

    BoxLayout:
      size_hint_y: 3
      Widget: # to fill the line from left

      Button:
        text: "Button"
        font_size: 40
        text_size: self.size     
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'bottom'
        padding_y: 10

        #Adding Image you can comment this part    
        Image:
          source: 'img/calender1.png'
          center_x: self.parent.center_x
          center_y: self.parent.center_y +10

      Widget:# to fill the line from right

    BoxLayout:
      size_hint_y: 10    

""")
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
  pass

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------    
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
      return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The main part goes in the Button. you can play with font, alignment and padding to get any desired result.

```
Button:
    text: "Button"
    font_size: 40
    text_size: self.size     
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'bottom'
    padding_y: 10
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid numbers in `text.size`, then try this:

`text_size: self.size`