# Centering multi-line Button or Label text in kivy?

Tags: kivy

In kivy, how do you go about creating Buttons or Labels with multiple lines of text which are automatically centered? If you do something like, `Button(text = 'my button\nthis is my button')`, it seems that only one of the lines will be centered, while the other line will be off-center. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just setting [halign](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=text%20alignment#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign) isn't enough, you need to set the [text_size](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=text%20alignment#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size) property which defines the size in which to restrict text. Then set `halign` and `valign`. For a detailed answer look here [Kivy button text alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334280/kivy-button-text-alignment-issue)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for halign](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=label#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign) indicates that the default is 'left'.

So you should set it to `center` instead:

```
Button(text = 'my button\nthis is my button', halign='center')
```

---

#### Full Example

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1') 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello world!\nGood bye, world!\nCentered?', halign='center')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Which produces this:

[image]