# How to align label and text input in one row with kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, alignment, grid-layout

I'm struggling to understand layout positioning in Kivy.

My aim is to create a simple form containing 3 rows, each one consisting of a label and a text input.

For example, like on this wireframe drawn with [PlantUML, Salt (source)](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAKxCAU6gvb9G2CelZpTK088Q1IMFr9oSV21J2Ifk11NN0W85975Zg7XuVb5E2bYybiiXDIy5P2W0):

[image: UI-prototype as rendered PlantUML using Salt]

### What I tried

I've tried combining different layouts but cannot achieve the right alignment and I also don't understand what's going wrong.

### First attempt:

KV file:

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    size_hint: .2, .1
    text_size: self.size
    
<CustomTextField@TextInput>:
    size_hint: .2, .1
    
<CustomFloatLayout@FloatLayout>:
    
<TestLayout>:     
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    CustomFloatLayout:
        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Field 1:'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .95}
        CustomTextField:
            hint_text: 'hint 1'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .92}
            
    CustomFloatLayout:
        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Field 2:'        
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .75}
        CustomTextField:
            hint_text: 'hint 2'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .72}    
            
    CustomFloatLayout:
        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Field 3:'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .55}
        CustomTextField:
            hint_text: 'hint 3'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .52}
```

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TestLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

##### Issue

The *y-center* of the labels is almost at the bottom of the *y-center* of the text input fields instead of being aligned at the same y-value. And what is even more puzzling: Each row has another offset from the left border of the window.

#### Second attempt:

KV file:

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    size_hint: .2, .1
    text_size: self.size
    
<CustomTextField@TextInput>:
    size_hint: .2, .1
        
<CustomBoxLayout@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    pos_hint: {'x': .1}
    

<TestLayout>:     
    CustomBoxLayout:
        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Field 1:'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .95}
        CustomTextField:
            hint_text: 'hint 1'
            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'center_y': .95}
            
    CustomBoxLayout:
        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Field 2:'        
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .75}
        CustomTextField:
            hint_text: 'hint 2'
            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'center_y': .75}    
            
    CustomBoxLayout:
        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Field 3:'
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'center_y': .55}
        CustomTextField:
            hint_text: 'hint 3'
            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'center_y': .55}
```

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TestLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

##### Issue

Looks better, but label and text input are still not aligned at the same center y value. In addition, if I change the `pos_hint` of e.g. the second `CustomLabel` to `pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'bottom': .75}`, then this label appears at the very bottom of the entire window. I would have expected it to be at the bottom of the current BoxLayout row.

### Question

1. How can I achieve a proper aligning of the labels and the text input fields?
2. Why are the labels/input fields of the **first attempt** located on the diagonal of the window?
3. Why do the labels appear at the bottom of the entire window when
   changing their bottom value within the **second attempt** code?

Comment: Well formulated question, with good attempts and clear questions. I added a prototype-/[wireframe image](https://plantuml.com/salt) (as far as I understood the desired layout). Correct ? Would help to see images showing issues with 1st and 2nd attempt.

Answer (score 2):

For your desired [layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/layouts.html) as *Grid* (arranging 3 rows with 2 columns) use `GridLayout`:

> **GridLayout**:
>
> Widgets are arranged in a grid defined by the `rows` and `cols` properties.

The order in automatic arrangement of widgets (using `add_widget`) is controlled by property [`orientation`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.orientation):

> orientation is an OptionProperty and defaults to ‘lr-tb’.

#### Python code (including widget declaration)

Adjusted from the examples in documentation of [`GridLayout`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#module-kivy.uix.gridlayout):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return layouted_widgets()  # replace this by `pass` for trying with KV


    def layouted_widgets():
        layout = GridLayout(rows=3, cols=2, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=40)
        # 1st row
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Label 1'))
        layout.add_widget(TextInput(text='Value 1', multiline=False, width=100))
        # 2nd row
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Label 2'))
        layout.add_widget(TextInput(text='Value 2', multiline=False, width=100))
        # 3rd row
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Label 3'))
        layout.add_widget(TextInput(text='Value 3', size_hint_x=None, width=100))
        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

See how the 3rd text-input is reduced in size to fit the text-value. This is because of the property `size_hint_x=None` which overrides the given `width=100`.

[image]

For specific positions inside each cell:

- you can not use property `pos_hint`
- for `Label` which is inherited from `Text`, same as `Button`: use `valign`, `halign` together with `text_size`. See the `Text`-based components' alignment explained in:
  [Kivy button text alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334280/kivy-button-text-alignment-issue)
- for `TextInput` use `padding` as explained in [Kivy TextInput horizontal and vertical align (centering text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477956/kivy-textinput-horizontal-and-vertical-align-centering-text)

The original Kivy Guide: Widgets, [Organize with Layouts](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html#organize-with-layouts) is a bit vague on that.

### KV file

Using both, your `Custom..` inherited widgets (1st and 2nd row) and the basic widgets (in 3rd row only):

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    # to add space from left and top-bottom, effects position x,y
    text_size: self.width - dp(20), self.height - dp(10)
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'center'

<CustomTextField@TextInput>:
    size_hint: self.width - dp(20), self.height - dp(10)
    # pos_hint: not supported as expected, thus use padding
    # left, right
    padding_x: dp(20)
    # top, bottom
    padding_y: dp(5)

GridLayout:
    rows: 3
    cols: 2
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height:40
    CustomLabel:
        text: 'Field 1:'
    CustomTextField:
        hint_text: 'hint 1'
    CustomLabel:
        text: 'Field 2:'        
    CustomTextField:
        hint_text: 'hint 2'
    Label:
        text: 'Field 3:'
    TextInput:
        hint_text: 'hint 3'
```

Renders the UI in 3 rows and 2 cols - almost all labels and text-inputs left-aligned. Only the 3rd label looks different to demonstrate the alignment-effect on others.
[image: GridLayout with aligns and padding]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the KV file you provided, it seems that the `pos_hint` for the `x`-value does not have any effect. Increasing this value does not lead to the text of the label moving to the right. If I remove the `text_size: self.size` row from the custom label, the label texts move to the right but I cannot control their exact position and they are not left-aligned with respect to each other (you can see this by changing the text "Field 1" to "Longfield 1"). Isn't it possible to control the position within the cells of a grid layout?

Comment: Also, could you please add an explanation on the 2nd and 3rd questions from my original post?